# Running slow from boot to shutdown

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I got a new computer custom built but with Windows installed about a year ago. I installed Ubuntu for dual boot with grub. It has i7-8700 cpu with 12 cores and 32 Gb RAM.

Generally speaking, it ran fine most of the time but a couple months ago it started running very slowly. I had hoped the 21.10 update would clear it up, but no luck. I have also had it start completely crashing periodically. Windows appears still to work fine.

I have searched for help but everything is either very basic (check RAM usage) or very specific (failure X is causing slow booting at this time stamp).  I keep the system monitor open as I work and my RAM usage is often below 20% with 0% swap used. All 12 cores show negligible use and the fans are at normal speed.

Even so, I have boots lasting upwards of 20 minutes if it doesn’t hang. I had a shutdown lasting over 10 minutes just now before I decided to go home because I need to get work done. Simple tasks like selecting an active window or switching virtual desktops often takes many seconds and keyboard input is just as bad.

Do I just need a complete reinstall action? Anyone have any suggestions about how to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Start with your logs. /var/log/syslog and journalctl.

Comment: Also, `systemd-analyze blame`. `sudo journalctl  -b 0` will show you logs starting at the most recent boot.

Comment: @waltinator I am not sure how to interpret the results of journalctl but they systemd-analyze blame command tells me that bootup is not yet finished.   It suggests to use systemctl list-jobs, which tells me that apport-autoreport.service is running the start type.